# iOS counterpart to androids AudioSource enumeration

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

Android has the `MediaRecorder.AudioSource` Enumeration. With it, Android applies preprocessing to the audio data for example with the `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` option.

Is there a counterpart to this on iOS? So far I am using `AudioInputQueue` to capture audio data from the microphone. However, I couldn't find an option which allows me to use basic preprocessing as with Androids `AudioSource` enumeration.

Since I am working with Xamarin, the solution I am looking for needs to be accessible through Xamarin.

Comment: Audio Units and Core Audio provide all the pre/post processing on iOS, which particular Android audio configuration are you trying to mirror?

Comment: I am building a app that can detect which person is speaking at a certain moment. In order to achieve this, every person participating in e.g. a meeting should have his phone lying in front of him with my app opened. Then the app calculates the volume each microphone captures and compares it. The phone that captures the highest volume should be the current speaker. I am trying to find the best audio configuration to achieve this. Probably on Android it is the `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` option.

Comment: There are *multiple* ways to do this, you can add a tap to the Audio mixer and monitor the audio stream (AVAudioEngine / MainMixer) or use an AVAudioSession and turn metering on (`IsMeteringEnabled`), etc.. I would advise you to read Apple Core Audio docs to determine which features your app is going to need and thus which iOS audio components you will need to use (as low level as a pure buffered byte stream of audio to a high level interface that provides a power/db indicator of an abstracted stream).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH10-SW7